# Accessing SharePoint DavWWWRoot from Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, webdav

We have a SharePoint internal corporate web site and I'd like to publish some PDFs to it automatically with Task Scheduler.

Currently we do this by hand. From my Windows 7 Enterprise desktop computer I can open path \portal.ourfirm.domain\DavWWWRoot\somepath in Windows Explorer and copy the PDFs there, and PDFs show up on the web. I can also do "pushd \portal.ourfirm.domain\DavWWWRoot\somepath" in cmd and do whatever I need.

Now I'd like to do the same thing from my Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard using Task Scheduler, since it is always on (as a virtual machine). The only problem is when I try to access that path from the server, it fails with:

```
Error code: 0x80004005
Error text: Windows cannot access \\portal.ourfirm.domain\DavWWWRoot\somepath
```

I asked both our Windows technician and network admin for help, but they cannot figure out what seems to be the problem, so the conclusion is "this can't be done". So I decided to try my luck here :-) Does aybody have an idea where I should start looking for a problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [this page](http://www.webdavsystem.com/server/access/windows), the Mini-Redirector (i.e. the WebDAV client) is not installed on Server 2008 and higher unless you [install the Desktop Experience feature](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754314.aspx).

Comment: Beautiful. Works like a charm. Who would have said I'd get an answer after 2 months :-D Great job!